# How to resize <div> on click and change back if clicked again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying it with this one, but sometimes the .click() just automaticly does the command not waiting for actual click.

```
var x = 0; 

if ($('#business').click() && (x = 0)) {
  $('#business').css('height', '500px');
  x = 1;
} else if ($('#business').click() && (x = 1)) {
  $('#business').css('height', '100px');
  x = 0;
}
```

I can resize it with the below code, but unfortunately dont know how to change back on click again.

```
$('#business').click(function(){
  $('#business').css('height', '500px')
})
```

Comment: Use the `.toggle()` method instead of `.css()`.

Comment: The top example isn't how events are handled. The bottom one is. You need to write a function to handle the click event that adds and removes a class or the css properties you're using. More info here in the [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/click/) documentation.

Comment: Toggle a class. No need to set size in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$('#business').click()`, it will actually simulate a click on your event.

If you want to have an action done *on* the click on your `div`, you should use your 2nd form:

```js
$('#business').click(function(){
  // Do whatever I want on click
})
```

In order to be able to change the height from one value to the other, you have two way for doing that:

1. Use a `data-*` property on your `div` element, test its value and set your height accordingly (and change the value of this property)
2. Get the current height of your element and change it accordingly

For instance, you could do something like this:

```js
$('#business').click(function(){
  if($('#business').css('height') === "500px")
    $('#business').css('height', '100px');
  else
    $('#business').css('height', '500px');
})
```

Comment: This works, but is really a mess and not the right approach. Just set up a class and use the `.toggle()` method to turn it off when it was on and vice versa.

Comment: Indeed, using a class is a nicer approach. My answer is a quick and dirty way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just toggle a class so there is no worrying about what state it should be in. Avoid setting css style properties directly in JavaScript.

```js
$(".foo").on("click", function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.foo {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.foo.active {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">1</div>
<div class="foo">2</div>
<div class="foo">3</div>
```